# Crash during secure erase in Disks utility and can no longer access drive

Tags: disk, sata, gnome-disk-utility

I started a secure erase operation in Ubuntu using the disk utility (example below) and the machine locked up, I rebooted it, and now can no longer access the disk. Upon booting, the BIOS asks for the disk password, which I have no idea what it would be. I've tried empty and my linux user password, neither of which work. I suppose my hope is that the Disk utility uses some default password during erase, and that someone on here knows what that would be. One final note, I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1121507/481874) which appears to have the answer I need, but unfortunately, I used the disk utility from the Live CD, thus, no logs.

[image]
[image]
[image: Disk Utility]

I also tried using `hdparm` to unlock the drive, using the above passwords as well.

- `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb`
  yields:

```
...
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
        enabled
        locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    Security level high
    564min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 564min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c500c2e9cd0d
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000c50
    Unique ID   : 0c2e9cd0d
Checksum: correct
```

- `sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-disable NULL /dev/sdb`
  yields:

```
/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_DISABLE command, password="", user=user
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 53 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

- `sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-disable mypassword /dev/sdb`
  yields:

```
/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_DISABLE command, password="mypassword", user=user
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 53 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

- `sudo hdparm --user-master m --security-disable mypassword /dev/sdb`
  yields:

```
/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_DISABLE command, password="mypassword", user=master
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 53 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

- `sudo hdparm --user-master m --security-disable NULL /dev/sdb`
  yields:

```
/dev/sdb:
 Issuing SECURITY_DISABLE command, password="", user=master
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 53 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misinterpreted what the other answer was saying, I didn't have to look in the logs, `xxxx` is the literal password.
So simply type:

```sh
sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-disable xxxx /dev/sdb
```

I just tried it and it works.

Hopefully if anyone else encounters this, it helps out.